# Run Fenics in Maya (Python)

Tags: python, docker, maya, fenics

I need to use a script in Maya that uses the Fenics Project libraries. Is there a way to do it?
Now I'm using Docker (out of Maya) and import the results in Maya, but I'd want to run the script from Maya itself

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a [mcve]. This question is likely too broad to attract responses which help you or the community.

Comment: I think you just have to find some build of Fenics compatible with your maya python version and then install manually Fenics into maya site-package